# WhatsApp disappears in Ultra Power Saving Mode

Tags: samsung, whatsapp-messenger, battery-saver

I just bought a Samsung Galaxy C9 Pro. Not sure what I did on the phone, when I change it to Ultra Power Saving Mode, WhatsApp disappears and I'm unable to use it. It worked well before but not sure why it disappeared suddenly.

I already removed and re-install WhatsApp on my phone but it didn't help.

Comment: May be the new Whatsapp version doesn't meet UPSM anymore. Try installing an old version just for testing

Comment: Hi, I just called Samsung technical support and they told me Whatsapp not support it..

Comment: But it still works on my phone (Galaxy J5, android 6.0.1)

Answer (score 1):

You can still use WhatsApp.

Just go to the Gallery, select any photo to share, and then you will get 3 options: one of them is WhatsApp. Just go ahead and select any contact. When WhatsApp is about to send the photo, click on the upper left-hand corner WhatsApp back button.

Then you will be able to use WhatsApp without any problem. Just remember not to clear your recent apps. If you clear that part, then you have to do the same processes again.